# Does $F$ represent a number or a vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, vectors, notation

If $F = ma$ and $F$ and $a$ are vectors, then how can $F$ and $a$ be given singular numbers as values? For example, $a = 10\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$ and $F = 20\ \mathrm{N}$. Are these singular numbers the lengths of the vectors $F$ and $a$, or are they some other value? For example if I have the vector $(a, b)$, then how can I calculate the force $F$ that that vector represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are the lengths or magnitudes (with signs) of the respective vectors.

Think of what a vector represents:

$$\vec F=\left(\begin{matrix}F_x\\F_y\\F_z\end{matrix}\right)\qquad \vec a=\left(\begin{matrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{matrix}\right)$$

A vector consists of its component lengths along each dimension ("a little out and a little in and a little up"). Written in the equation:

$$\vec F=m\vec a\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \left(\begin{matrix}F_x\\F_y\\F_z\end{matrix}\right) =m\left(\begin{matrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{matrix}\right)$$

The equations along each dimension are easily extracted:

$$\vec F=m\vec a\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \left(\begin{matrix}F_x\\F_y\\F_z\end{matrix}\right) =m\left(\begin{matrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{matrix}\right)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \begin{cases} F_x=&ma_x\\F_y=&ma_y\\F_z=&ma_z\end{cases} $$

And here you have the scalar versions of the vector equation. Were the x-axis placed along the vectors themselves, the x-components would happen to equal the vector's lengths / magnitudes (with signs), which is the case you described.

Comment: @Farcher I am not sure of what you are referring to. That should be covered in the last paragraph, no?

Comment: @Farcher Aha yes, that is a technical detail. Thanks for pointing it out. I have slightly edited that paragraph and hope that this meaning will be clear from the full answer

Comment: I don't like the statement that the numbers are magnitudes, because you can have $F = ma$ with negative force and acceleration, but that wouldn't make sense if they were magnitudes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you see $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{a}$ as single numbers, you're dealing with motion in one dimension (i.e. along a line), in which case the vectors are one-dimensional. A one-dimensional vector has only a single component, which you can write out as a number for simplicity.